# How to execute the following code at the same time?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

```
- (void)test{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    [currentBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    currentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    for (UIButton *btn in btnArray) {
        if (btn.tag != currentBtn.tag) {
            [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
    for (UIView *view in viewArray) {
        if (view.tag != currentView.tag) {
            [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }
    }
} completion:nil];
}
```

What can I do to execute these two for-loops just like only in one for loop?

Comment: Why? They are loops over different things

Comment: Not only are they looping over different things, but they're also doing different operations on them. Keeping it as 2 loops is likely a better choice for readability & simplicity.

Comment: Your are correct, i mean `[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];` the `btn` & the `view` should change their `backgroundColor` at the same time. when there are too many btns ang views, when we see the UI,we will feel delay.

Comment: All of those animations will occur at the same time, the order of operations in that block doesn't determine the order of animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your structure.

If the button is a subview of the view, then you could just iterate over your view array, change the background. Then get the subview (button) from it and set the title color.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    [currentBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    currentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    for (UIView *view in viewArray) {
        if (view.tag != currentView.tag) {
            [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)view.subviews[0];
            [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
} completion:nil];
```

Or, if the button is not a subview or the view, but there are the same number of element in both viewArray and binary, then you could use a for-loop and use the loop value to access each array's element.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    [currentBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    currentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    for (int i = 0; i < MIN(btnArray.count, viewArray.count); i++) {
        UIButton *btn = btnArray[i];
        if (btn.tag != currentBtn.tag) {
            [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        UIView *view = viewArray[i];
        if (view.tag != currentView.tag) {
            [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }
    }
} completion:nil];
```